Como generar una condición especifica para la simulación?
Buen día, requiero crear una simulación donde obtenga valores de un vector (1,4) , en el ejemplo será "tetha", donde tetha genera la variable IDH_New que es un producto de tetha con otra variable condicionado por la variable "dominio", luego se genera una variable IDH que es el orden de menor a mayor de la variable "IDH_New", lo que busco es encontrar los valores "Tetha" que me permita cumplir las siguientes condiciones
(sum((INCORE-IDH)/26)<0.1) ,(abs(INCORE-IDH)<=2),
(cor(IDH,INCORE)>=0.75)
en el caso que no cumpla el valor de Tetha , va a aumentado en 0.1 hasta obtener el valor optimo de cada componente de Tetha.
Gracias
``` letras <- LETTERS
ids <- 1:length(letras)


set.seed(123)  # Establecer la semilla para reproducibilidad
INCORE <- sample(1:26)
IDH_V <- runif(26, min = 1, max = 10)
IDH <- rank(-IDH_V, ties.method = "first")
DOMINIO<-sample(1:4, 26, replace = TRUE)
base_datos <- data.frame(Nombre = letras, ID = ids , INCORE=INCORE, IDH = IDH, IDH_V=IDH_V)
    
g<-function(theta,z){

  a_1<-theta[1]
  a_2<-theta[2]
  a_3<-theta[3]
  a_4<-theta[4]
  

  
  IDH_New<-ifelse(DOMINIO==1, a_1*IDH_V,
                  ifelse(DOMINIO==2, a_2*IDH_V,
                         ifelse(DOMINIO==3, a_3*IDH_V, a_4*IDH_V)))
  
  
  
  

  IDH <- rank(-IDH_New, ties.method = "first")
  return(IDH)
}
    
theta0<-c(0,0,0,0)
res<-matrix(theta0,1,4)
cont<-0
h<-0
while(cont==0){
  h<-h+1
  theta.old<-res[h,]
        
  theta.new<-????????????????????????
                   
  res<-rbind(res,theta.new)
  if((sum((INCORE-IDH)/26)<0.1) && (abs(INCORE-IDH)<=2) && (cor(IDH,INCORE)>=0.75)){cont<-1}
}
res 


